# Symfony APC caches wrong content

Tags: caching, symfony1, apc

Hy,

so I inherited a symfony 1.3.8 application using APC as caching mechanism. Even so I disabled caching by using

```yml
default:
  enabled:     false
  with_layout: false
  lifetime:    86400
```

an entry with the key `*.symfony.routing.data` is still saved.

Everytime I open a link directing to a PDF document `$host/$app/erhebung/13398/ausweise.pdf` I generated using a plugin, the second time I open that link I get an error:

```
Action "erhebung/13398" does not exist., referer: …
```

The cache does - after the first call - containt the serialized value of

```
array(2) {
  'parse_/erhebung/13398/ausweise.pdf_b0d96fa30dcf0130d6a4b26f14f44bfb' =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(7) "default"
    'pattern' =>
    string(18) "/:module/:action/*"
    'parameters' =>
    array(3) {
      'module' =>
      string(8) "erhebung"
      'action' =>
      string(5) "13398"
      'ausweise.pdf' =>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
  'generate__4d783133e9aa851733d16cf1d1750ad5_b0d96fa30dcf0130d6a4b26f14f44bfb' =>
  string(1) "/"
}
```

which seems to be the wrong routing pattern, it should be:

```yml
erhebung_ausweise:
  url:   /erhebung/:id/ausweise.pdf
  param: { module: erhebung, action: ausweise }
  requirements: { id: \d+ }
```

instead of:

```yml
default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

When I clear the APC cache manually I can generate and open the PDF once again.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, it took me several days to resolve this issue, I used `xhprof` as other tools like `xdebug` and `print_debug_backtrace` wouldn't work.

I will describe what lead to that issue.

The same url was routed twice. First to run the right request handler and second by mistake. My predecessor use a homegrown `cross_app_url`-function that would read the routing configuration of another app. During this process the uri was parsed again and the result (nothing found using the default route) was cached (again). Hence the second time the uri was called the first routing to the request handler faild and hence the error.

I hope if anybody ever runs into the same issue (s)he will find this easier than me.